# Formato de apresentação TimeField no Django

Tags: python, django

```
class Passagem(models.Model):
    inscricao = models.ForeignKey(Inscricao, verbose_name='inscricao', related_name='passagem',
                              on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    hora_passagem = models.TimeField('Tempo', auto_now_add=True)
```

Tenho essa tabela onde grava a `hora_passagem`, que é do tipo `TimeField`. Ao apresentar no sistema web, ela apresenta do seguinte formato: `"14:35"`.

Como faço para que apresente nesse formato : `"14:34:58.943943"`

Estou utilizando o Django 2.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No Django existe o filtro no [`date`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#date) no template que você pode utilizar para formatar a data:

```
{% for obj in objs %}
    <h1>{{ obj.hora_passagem|date:'H:i:s:u' }}</h1>
{% endfor %}
```

Isso para um modelo semelhante à:

```
from django.db import models

class Passagem(models.Model):
    hora_passagem = models.TimeField()
```

E uma `view`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Passagem

# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    objs = Passagem.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'main/index.html', {'objs': objs})
```

Veja funcionando em https://LopsidedFumblingTypes--acwoss.repl.co ou o código fonte no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/LopsidedFumblingTypes).

Comment: Perfeito, consegui fazer com que aparecesse do jeito que eu queria. Muito Obrigado!